# "The application has stopped unexpectedly" error in Android

Tags: android

java file---Bttest11.java

```
**package niebttest11.example.bluetoothtesta;
/*import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class Bttest11 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bttest11);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bttest11, menu);
        return true;
    }
    */
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Bttest11 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

        int state = intent.getExtras().getInt(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE);

     switch (state) {

   case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:

      Toast.makeText(context, "Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           break;

   case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:

   Toast.makeText(context, "Turning Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

     case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
            Toast.makeText(context, "On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          break;

 case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:

      Toast.makeText(context, "Turning On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         break;
        }
    }
}**



//manifest file---Bluetoothtest11 Manifest


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="niebttest11.example.bluetoothtesta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="niebttest11.example.bluetoothtesta.Bttest11"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="Bttest11" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACTION_FOUND"/>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ERROR:

The code is running.But while running .apk in an android phone,it will show an error that,

> "The application Bluetoothtest11(process nietest11.example.buetoothtesta) has stopped unexpectedly".

Comment: Did you use the debugger? You can attach the eclipse debugger to the phone process. Also, the logcat will most likely have a stack trace for you. Please try and do the leg work yourself instead of just posting your code here.

Comment: post some logs to analyze?

Comment: Please post the logcat too

Answer (score 0):

If you use only BroadcastReceiver  then dont write Bttest11 in activity bcoz that not a activity.

and 
if you want activity then create one activity class and call receiver from there.
define that activity in android manifest. under activity tag
and your receiver write in receiver tag

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
}
```

}